# How to horizontally center a form accross a page?

Tags: html

I have an HTML doc that looks roughly like this:

```
<html>
  <head><title>Example</title></head>
  <body>
     <div id="main_content" style="width:90%;">
         <form id="searchbox" method="post" action="#">
             <input type="text" name="search" />
             <input type="submit />
         </form>
     </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

How do I (horizontally) center the search form in  the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using CSS:

- assign it a `width`
- use `margin-left:auto`, `margin-right:auto`